# Simple Add to time and compare GO

Tags: go

Hi I can't seem to get my head around the correct way to do time arithmetic in Go.

I have a time "object" later initialized to [Now()](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now) and stored.

```
   insertTime time.Time
```

Later, I need to see if the item is older than 15 minutes.

How do i do this?
Do I need to create a [Duration](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) of 15 Minutes add it to the current time and compare? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[func (Time) After](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.After) will be helpful, I believe. Schema:

```
when := time.Now()

...

if time.Now().After(when.Add(15*time.Minute)) {
        // Conditionally process something if at least 15 minutes elapsed
}
```

Instead of a variable, `when` could be a field of some struct, for example.

Alternative approach:

```
deadline := time.Now().Add(15*time.Minute)

...

if time.Now().After(deadline) {
        // Conditionally process something if at least 15 minutes elapsed
}
```

I prefer the later version personally.

Comment: Thank you, now it all makes sense! It was a bit tricky to understand the time constants.

Comment: @jnml don't you think that in the two examples, the condition "Is the present instant after the deadline" would be better expressed as `if time.Now().After(deadline)` and resp. `if time.Now().After(when.Add(15*time.Minute))` ?  (not the other way around)